# Correct way to compare time using date_sub(now())

Tags: php, mysql

I have a simple query to the database

```
$query  = SELECT * FROM login WHERE > date_sub(now(), interval 5);
```

I have also used the following statement but I get the same result

```
$query  = SELECT * FROM login WHERE last_seen > date_sub(now(), interval 5);
```

I wish to retrieve everything from table login where the time is at an interval of 5 secs using `date_sub(now() , interval 5)`

I have stored the DATETIME datatype in a column called last_seen within table login

[image: Table Layout]

My desired outcome is see some result such as

RESULT expectations -> Tom 2020-05-07 17:40:48

My Error

> syntax error, unexpected 'login' (T_STRING) in /var/www/html/website/action/action_online.php on line 14

My code

```
$query  = SELECT * FROM 'login' WHERE > date_sub(now(), interval 5);
$select_stmt_type->close();
$statement = $conn->prepare($query);
$statement->execute();
$result = $statement->fetchAll();
```

Comment: interval of 5 what? seconds?

Comment: Yes 5 secs , correct.

Comment: @TryHarder have you tried [reading the MySQL manual pages](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-sub)?

Comment: @Martin I didn't realize the separate line that he wrote was a copy of what he wrote inside the query.

Comment: You need to wrap the SQL in PHP string. Use quotes.

Comment: You tagged it with mysqli, but you do not use mysqli. You use PDO, but even then I don't see what it has to do with PDO, so I removed the tag.

Comment: @Martin OP is clearly using PDO. mysqli_stmt doesn't have a method called `fetchAll`. There's quite a lot of difference between them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## 1)

Your SQL query needs to be wrapped in quotes and treated as a [*string* PHP type](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php).

```
    $query  = "SELECT * FROM login WHERE > date_sub(now(), interval 5)";
```

## 2)

You can read the MySQL Manaul Pages about the correct syntax to use for your [`date_sub` function](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-sub) and the [`interval` part](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/expressions.html#temporal-intervals).

## 3)

You appear to have a syntax error on *some* of your code, where you have not referenced the column name you're comparing against the `date_sub` function.

*(No idea if this is a typo or actually an error?)*

## 4)

Use the correct quotes. SQL column and table names are wrapped in "backticks" **NOT** single or double quotes. Single quotes are for string literals in SQL. For example, the table and column names in the code below is now encased in backticks.

## Bringing this all together:

```
$query  = "SELECT * FROM `login` WHERE `last_seen` > date_sub(now(), INTERVAL 5 SECOND)";
$statement = $conn->prepare($query);
$statement->execute();
$result = $statement->fetchAll();
```

## Bonus:

Because your query does not contain any variable placeholders you can simply do a [`->query` call](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.query.php) rather than a `->prepare` call.

```
$result = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM `login` WHERE `last_seen` > date_sub(now(), INTERVAL 5 SECOND)")
foreach ($result as $row){
    print_r($row); //output's each row returned by the SQL
}
```

Comment: @Martin you still didn't put the query in a string.

Answer (score 1):

Your query needs to be in quotes, the column your comparing to specified, and the type of interval specified.  Also, remove single quotes from 'login', or use back-ticks.

```
    $query  = "SELECT * FROM login WHERE columnName > date_sub(now(), interval 5 SECOND)";
```